# Finding time complexity of a depth first traversal algorithm with a depth limit to get all node traversals starting from the root node

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, graph-traversal, depth-first-search

What would be the time complexity of a depth-first traversal algorithm on a graph, that is simply trying to retrieve all nodes being visited from starting node up until a depth limit is reached (i.e. same node can be visited multiple times if cycles are present). The idea here is to retrieve an ordered list of nodes that are reached (regardless of the fact that a given node was visited previously). How would I approach this problem? Any helpful input or a link to a resource that I could refer to would be appreciated!

Comment: why not apply BFS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm till depth $d$?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami I need to traverse in a depth-first manner. If I use BFS, the order of nodes being visited varies right?

Comment: I did not understand what you mean. Please elaborate.

Comment: The order of reaching nodes varies when I use BFS as I have to first take care of all the adjacent nodes before going into level 2. Why I want to use DFS is because I want the order of reaching nodes to be depth first. Sorry about the poor explanation. Hopefully, you got what I meant.

Comment: Even if you apply DFS there could be many different ordering?